# Hide code folding icon in SublimeText

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Is there any way to hide the little yellow icons [...] shown when using code folding in SublimeText(2)?

I'm working with code that needs to be heavily commented and using the [fold comments package](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Fold%20Comments), so when just working with code, all these icons are distracting me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here: https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=16262#p61284

> Create a folder called `Theme - Default` in your `Packages` folder, and copy your `fold.png` variant there.

<sup>You can get to your `Packages` folder through "Browse Packages" in Command Pallet <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd></sup>

`fold.png` has to be 16 x 16px, and unfortunately you can't make it 0 length to hide it entirely. Best you could do is make it completely transparent. Here is mine: [`fold.png`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CI0bd.png)

Comment: Thanks! A small dot works fine for me, indicating a fold but not distracting when having several code folds in a row.